# Path that visual studio uses to look for a resource file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, resources

I am using visual studio 2005 to build a c++ project. This project contains a resource file (.rc) file which includes another resource file (also a .rc).

Building this complains
**fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'WrappedGrid.rc'**

Now , I have the directory this is located in the the c++-->Additional Include Directories.. But i suspect, the path for resource files is to be specified somewhere else.

Anyone know where this might be?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a separate section named "Resources" in the project settings, which contains another "Additional Include Directories" setting.